# How to establish a 2 way communication using sockets in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, client-server, google-compute-engine, python-sockets

So, I have a server script that receives an image from a client script and is supposed to send an acknowledgement saying "OK". But the acknowledgement never goes through.

Server script -

```
import socket,sys               

s = socket.socket()         
print("Socket successfully created")

port =80                

s.bind(('', port))        
print("socket binded to %s" %(port))
s.listen(5)     
print("socket is listening")            

while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print('Got connection from', addr)
   file_name=s.recv(1024)
   file_name=fil_ename.decode("utf-8")
   with open(file_name,"wb")as f:
      while True:
         data=c.recv(1024)
         if not data:
            break
         f.write(data)

   c.send(bytes('Thank you ! File received.',"utf-8"))
   c.close()
```

Client script -

```
import socket            

s = socket.socket()         

# Define the port on which you want to connect
port = 80              

s.connect(('IP address of my server', port))
s.send(bytes("hand.jpeg","utf-8"))
f=open("back.jpeg","rb")
data=f.read(512)
while data:
    s.send(data)
    data=f.read(512)
f.close()
print(s.recv(10))
```

The server does not send any acknowledgement and seems to get stuck in the for loop. But if i remove the line `c.send(bytes('Thank you ! File received.',"utf-8"))`  from the server script, the code works well. Also, if I remove the receive part from server side and just send the acknowledgent part , i.e `c.send(bytes('Thank you ! File received.',"utf-8"))` , the client receives the message. But If a combination of receive(the image file) and the acknowledgement is made in the server side as shown in the code, the server side fails to respond.

Important thing to note is that on KeyBoardInterrupt-ing the above program, it shows that the server side script is hanged/stuck in the `data=c.recv(1024)` line. But the same problem vanishes if the acknowledgement line is removed.

Note:- The client side script is running on my local machine and the server side script is running on a Google Cloud VM Instance.

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I don't think I completely believe your description of the behavior. But I do know what's wrong. It's entirely reasonable that your server is sitting in the receive loop, because the client hasn't signaled EOF to the connection. Under what circumstances do you believe that this will actually `break`?

```
if not data:
    break
```

The answer is that the client needs to either `close` the socket, or use `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` to indicate that it will not be sending any more data. So to do what you want, on the client side:

```
...
f.close()
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
...
```

Now the next time the server calls `recv`, it will get an empty string returned and the `break` above will be taken.

This leaves the connection open in one direction but not the other. So the client will not be able to send any more data. However, the server will still be able to send to the client until *it* closes the socket (or uses `shutdown` itself).

There is another more subtle problem. You are assuming that your first server-side `recv` will receive only and exactly the bytes containing your file name. 99.9% of the time that will work. But it's possible that the data from your next client-side `send` will *also* be available when the server calls `recv` for the first time. That will likely give you a bogus file name (though not necessarily an illegal one) and will certainly mean that your file is not transferred faithfully.

You should never assume that the data provided by a single `send` by one peer will be received by a corresponding single `recv` on the other side. The data received could be more or less and it's up to the application to frame the data to ensure that it receives exactly the intended amount.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I realise my mistake now. Just to add on to what you explained above, assuming that along with the file name, some redundant data is also transmitted, how would I prevent it ? Should I shutdown from the client side,once the filename is transmitted and wait for it's acknowledgement ? If I do that I won't be  able to transfer the image contents itself. Im sorry, I am new to this networking side of python so idk how I would actually establish this 2 way connection.

Comment: Or, how do I send an EOF reliably ? I have tried sending a custom EOF like `xxxclosexxx` and then tried to decode it on the server side but it kept throwing me utf-8  decoding error.

Comment: Okay I figured out a way to send the EOF. I have sent the length of the file before sending the actual image, to alert the server about the total incoming bytes and then sent  one byte at a time for the image transfer. In this method, my socket is open even after the transfer has taken place and thus I can send another message If needed. Thanks fro the help though.

Comment: Yes. Typically protocols are either binary (you send a length [itself encoded in a fixed-length binary field with a specified byte ordering] before each element; on receiving side you read the fixed-length field which tells you the size of the subsequent variable length field), or they are text-based like HTTP 1.X in which case you have some reserved separator that allows you to parse the elements (HTTP uses CR-LF as separator). A binary protocol is a bit more difficult to set up for a beginner but in the long run, makes parsing on receiving side *much* simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
while True:
    data=c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
       break
    f.write(data)
```

it loops back to waiting for a message after it has received one because you don't break the while loop after receiving data. the `if not data:` doesn't do anything since `recv()` stops and waits until it gets a message, and thus `data` is never nothing. You should either break the loop after receiving a message by adding a `break` after `f.write(data)`, or send the OK in the loop.

Comment: So how do I break the loop,once all my data is received ?